# Simple use of static in java

Tags: java, static, static-members

I understand the purpose of static keyword but regretfully I can't figure out this simple code. Don't know why? I'm expecting the answer to be really simple.

```
public class VariableScope {

    int x=y;
    static int y=5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new VariableScope().x); 
    }
}
```

How x gets printed as 5 when y was assigned to it at an earlier stage?

Comment: What do you expect it to print? When you do think the `static` assignment happens? Please **enumerate explicitly** what you expect to happen?

Comment: Because all statics are initialised before everything else (in your case, local x) when the programme is launched.

Comment: @hagubear this is an utterly fallacious over-simplification.

Comment: This is example 8.3.2.2-1 in the JLS [Initializers for Instance Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.1)  The adjacent sections are also good reads: Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization and Initializers for Class Variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The static initialization `static int y = 5` happens during class loading.

The `x = y` assignment happens during the instance construction `new VariableScope()`; so at this point `y` has the value `5` already.

Comment: Simple and correct! If only there were more answers like this!

Answer (score 2):

It's because order the lines of the code does not matter here. Static member is initialized first, then x is initialized.

Here is detailed specification of the initialization order: [Java Language Specification 12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)